# Correct use of multiple AND, OR MySQL statements

Tags: php, mysql

I got confused when using multiple AND, OR Mysql statements.
For example i have this query:

```
$ip_sql= $connector->query("select count(id) AS count FROM likes WHERE 
content_id='$id' AND (ip='$ip' OR user='$_SESSION[user_id]')");
    $rw90 = $connector->fetchArray($ip_sql);
    $count = $rw90['count'];

    if($count==0) {...}
```

Here i try to check if a user liked a content. I want to make a double check:

1. Search if user is in likes table
2. Check if his IP is in likes table
3. If both conditions return 0 result is OK

I think i can do it by 2 queries, something like:

```
$result1 = $connector->query("SELECT count(id) as cn FROM likes 
WHERE user='$current_user' AND content_id='$id'");
$row1 = $connector->fetchArray($result1);
if($row1['cn'] > 0) {/*stop here*/}
else {
$result2 = $connector->query("SELECT count(id) as cn2 FROM likes 
WHERE ip='$current_ip' AND content_id='$id'");
$row2 = $connector->fetchArray($result2);
if($row2['cn2']>0) {/*stop here*/}
else {/*it's ok!*/}
}
```

But i want to gather those 2 queries in 1. My first code doesnt return what i need. Thank you in advance

Just tried following code. It doesnt work as well

```
select count(id) AS count 
from likes where content_id='$id' and ((ip='$ip' OR user='$_SESSION[user_id]') OR (ip='$ip' AND user='$_SESSION[user_id]'))
```

Comment: Seperate logical units using brackets for improved readability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"select count(id) AS count FROM likes WHERE 
content_id='" . $id . "' AND (ip='" .$ip . "' OR user='" . $_SESSION[user_id] . "')";
```

Your initial query looks correct -> just try this to make sure the variables are being passed in correctly. If it doesnt work let me know and I will help you get to the right answer!

Comment: thank you for your attention. problem solved. the reason was not on this query.